# Android OpenGL passing OnTouch event value

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm having problem. I don't know how to pass the value x and y in the `OnTouch` method to the private final class MyRenderer and update the `OnDrawFrame` tex.draw(,x,y,,,) function x and y value to be able to translate the object I want to move with my finger.

Any guidance with be appreciated~

```
public class Stage extends GLSurfaceView{

// Stage width and height
private float w, h;

// Screen width and height
private int screenWidth, screenHeight;

// Our native vertex buffer
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

private Texture tex;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    float x, y;
    int pointerIndex;
    int pointerId;

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        pointerIndex = 0;
    } else {
        pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
        pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
        y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
    }
    Log.v("this X", String.valueOf(x));
    Log.v("this Y", String.valueOf(y));

    return true;
}

public Stage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
    setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  // 2. left-top
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f   // 3. right-top
    };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    tex = new Texture(R.drawable.kdk);

}

private final class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public final void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        tex.prepare(gl, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        tex.draw(gl, w / 2, h / 2, tex.getWidth(), tex.getHeight(), 0);

    }

    public final void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if(width > height) {
            h = 600;
            w = width * h / height;
        } else {
            w = 600;
            h = height * w / width;
        }
        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public final void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set up alpha blending
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // We are in 2D. Why needs depth?
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // Enable vertex arrays (we'll use them to draw primitives).
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // Enable texture coordination arrays.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        tex.load(getContext());
    }

}

}
```

Other coding

[How to apply drag drop and scale in Android OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556914/how-to-apply-drag-drop-and-scale-in-android-opengl-es/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will have to add a **MyRenderer** attribute to your **Stage** class.

This solution will work but it is maybe not the best so fell free to comment.

---

1. You need to change the definition of your inner class **MyRenderer** by removing the `final` statement :

   **EDIT** : I am not sure about this one because `final class` will have all its methods set to final but maybe not the attributes. If someone can answer it I'll be glade to read it.

   > private final class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer

   To

   > private class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer

---

2. In your **Stage** class :

   ```
   public class Stage extends GLSurfaceView {

       // Stage width and height
       private float w, h;

       ...

       // The renderer
       MyRenderer mRenderer;

       ...

       public Stage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

           mRenderer = new MyRenderer();

           super(context, attrs);
           setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);

           setRenderer(mRenderer);

           ...
       }
   }
   ```

---

3. Add the setters to your **MyRenderer** class :

   ```
   private class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

       float xPos;
       float yPos;

       // ...

       public void setX(float x) {
           xPos = x;
       }

       public void setY(float y) {
           yPos = y;
       }

       public void setXY(float x, float y) {
           xPos = x;
           yPos = y;
       }
   }
   ```

---

4. Finally set these values in the `OnTouch` method.

---

### Edit :

To set the xPos and yPos default value :

```
private class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    float xPos;
    float yPos;

    boolean initialised = false;

    ...

    public final void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        if (!initialised) {
            xPos = width /2;
            yPos = height / 2;
            initialised = true;
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

---

### EDIT 2 :

To avoid race condition set the X and Y value at the same time with one function. When entering the method it will create temporary variable with the value passed in parameters. This will ensure that the x and y value passed are from the same Event.

```
private class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    float xPos;
    float yPos;

    // ...


    public void setXY(float x, float y) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's work! thanks bro but I still have 1 question, how can I save my xPos and yPos value to default w/2 and h/2 ?

Comment: in your **onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)** method you can, the first time you enter this method, set its value. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Ya Sir, it's worked, but when I dragging the object, the object keep on glitching, probably my onTouch method having problem with the pointer touch id...

Comment: @KenChong This could be a refresh issue. If you need to fix this but you don't know how, ask another question by describing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I will try to fix it, probably will ask stackoverflow if I fail.

Comment: This code has race conditions. If the UI thread calls `setX()` followed by `setY()`, the rendering thread could use the values while one of them has updated, but the other one still has the old value.

Comment: Then how to overcome the race condition?

Comment: It's weird when I removed public void setX(float x) {
        xPos = x;
    }
the setX function still work.... after I added import android.annotation.TargetApi;

Comment: I think the value is still unable to pass, the setX function is from import android.annotation.TargetApi; which mean this function public void setX(float x) { xPos = x; } is useless

Comment: @KenChong I named the methods `setX` and `setY` but you can rename them. If the methods already exists in the parent class it is for a reason so just change the name like `setXPosition` in order to keep the other ones working. But if you don't need these methods simply don't use them :)

Comment: Ya this problem was solved, the texture don't move because of missing requestRender(); after call the setXPosition and setYPosition..

Comment: @KenChong I also edited my answer to avoid race condition

Comment: Oh ya race condition can be avoid by using synchronized () function