# Android OpenGL-ES unable to pass value from touch event

Tags: android, opengl-es

What's wrong with my coding? When I drag the texture using my finger, the texture keep on blinking and move between other place and the pointer place.

Any guidance will be appreciated~

This is the coding:

```
public class Stage extends GLSurfaceView{

// Stage width and height
private float w, h;

// Screen width and height
private int screenWidth, screenHeight;

// Our native vertex buffer
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

private Texture tex;

MyRenderer mRenderer;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    float x, y;
    int pointerIndex;
    int pointerId;

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        pointerIndex = 0;
    } else {
        pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
        pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
        y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
    }
    mRenderer.setXY(x, y);
    Log.v("X: ", String.valueOf(x));
    Log.v("Y: ", String.valueOf(y));
    return true;
}

public Stage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
    mRenderer = new MyRenderer();
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  // 2. left-top
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f   // 3. right-top
    };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    tex = new Texture(R.drawable.kdk);

}

private class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    public void setXY(float x, float y) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            xPos = x;
            yPos = y;
        }
    }

    public final void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        tex.prepare(gl, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        synchronized (lock) {
            tex.draw(gl, xPos, yPos, tex.getWidth(), tex.getHeight(), 0);
        }

    }

    public final void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if(width > height) {
            h = 600;
            w = width * h / height;
        } else {
            w = 600;
            h = height * w / width;
        }
        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;

        xPos = w/2;
        yPos = h/2;

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public final void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set up alpha blending
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // We are in 2D. Why needs depth?
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // Enable vertex arrays (we'll use them to draw primitives).
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // Enable texture coordination arrays.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        tex.load(getContext());
    }

}

}
```

Other classes coding:

[How to apply drag drop and scale in Android OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556914/how-to-apply-drag-drop-and-scale-in-android-opengl-es/)

Comment: It doesn't quite explain your symptoms, but yo should call `requestRender()` on the `GLSurfaceView` instance after updating the values. Otherwise it will generally not redraw.

Comment: Ya, this is the function i missed out, it make me faint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, one possible cause is that, as the updating of `xPos` and `yPos` by the UI thread is not synchronized with the render thread, some of the frames would be drawn with `xPos` updated but not `yPos` and at a wrong position.  This is corrected in the next rendering cycle, causing some flickering.

You may need to use some means of synchronization to ensure that when `onDrawFrame()` is called, the state (`xPos` and `yPos`) is consistent.

**Edit**: There are many ways to do so, e.g. by using a lock. In the renderer-

```
private Object lock = new Object();

public void setXY(float x, float y) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }
}

public final void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    tex.prepare(gl, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    synchronized (lock) {
        tex.draw(gl, xPos, yPos, tex.getWidth(), tex.getHeight(), 0);
    }
}
```

(you also need to modify the call under `onTouchEvent()` to `setXY(x, y);`)

**Further Edit:**

As you have used `setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);` you need to call `requestRender();` after updating the position on the onTouchEvent handler as mentioned by Reto Koradi above:

```
mRenderer.setXY(x, y);
requestRender();
```

In this case the synchronization code may not be necessary since the rendering is only triggered by `requestRender()` after both x and y are updated, and most probably would not take place in parallel.

Comment: When I print the float x and y it's show the x value always negative, what's wrong with this?

Comment: This is another question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237200/motionevent-gety-and-getx-return-incorrect-values

Comment: Ah just remove the `static` from the lock as there should be only one instance of the renderer.

Comment: there is never use of setXY function and unable to call setXY

Comment: Call mRenderer.setXY in your onTouchEvent, instead  of calling setX and setY separately

Comment: Ya can't, previously the setX function also not work, it work because of import android.annotation.TargetApi;

Comment: Did you miss `mRenderer`? i.e. call `mRenderer.setXY(x,y);`

Comment: Ya, it's true, I'm trying now thanks bro, you helped me

Comment: The error come out FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 960
    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I think the lock problem, the error is on the line synchronized (lock) { tex.draw or the private field lock never used

Comment: My bad, forgot to call `new Object()`. code modified.

Comment: I have updated my code, you can have a see, now the texture not move at all, I think the x and y value not pass from the touch method to the onDrawFrame

Comment: OK try to test it myself.

Comment: Full coding of other class is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556914/how-to-apply-drag-drop-and-scale-in-android-opengl-es/

Comment: Turn out that it is a problem elsewhere - you set the render mode to `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY`.  So immediately after `mRenderer.setXY(x, y);` you need to call `requestRender();`.  Separately, as advised in the answer from which you get the code, you need to set `xPos = x * w / screenWidth;` and `yPos = y * h / screenHeight;` for correct position calculation.

Comment: Thanks Bro you help me a lot, I am appreciate it~

Comment: For future readers of this QA you may consider reverting the code in the question above to the original one, and list the issues encountered.

Comment: Sir, I have an question, it's possible to add a onClickListener on the texture?

Comment: You may use a gesturedetector in the onTouchEvent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton . Perhaps you should ask a separate question if that answer does not help.

Comment: But that one not a button, is a texture draw with OpenGL

Comment: The mechanism is the same. You feed the gesturedetector with MotionEvent, and the gesture detector will determine if a click has taken place.   If you have any problem on this may be you should open a separate new question of detecting both touch and click events on a opengl texture, pointing to this question on the code.

Comment: I mean texture have no id like the button have

Comment: You do not need any id to use the gesture detector. You are already intercepting the touch events, and can feed the events to the detector.

Comment: I think I need to spend time to study it again, anyway thanks bro!

Comment: I have post a new question about how to set a touch/click listener for the texture in OpenGL-ES but I still question it's possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834363/how-to-set-ontouch-listener-for-drawn-texture-in-android-opengl-es

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by queueing events (from the Touch listener) to the GLThread by calling queueEvent() of GLSurfaceView
Pass the x, y parameters in the runnable posted alongwith.

```
Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRenderer.setXY(x, y);
    }
}
```

Assign x and y to global variables,

And replace

```
mRenderer.setXY(x, y);
```

with

```
queueEvent(mRunnable);
```

And then call requestRender() in order to request redrawing.

On the GLRenderer's side, set the x, y params to the ones received from the runnable.
And use the values in onDraw() method.

And **remove the synchronisation blocks**, since everything is now happening in GL thread itself.

Comment: Thanks Sahil, appreciate your answer